# jQuery Early Binding a Function Possible?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a small issue with a bit of jQuery:

```
function getQuickResults(terms) 
{ 
   var url = '/Search/PreviewSearch';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { terms: terms },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success: function(json) {

            $("#quickSearchResults").empty();

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                var title = json[i].Title;

                $("#quickSearchResults").append($("<span class='quickSearchResult' />"))
                                        .children(":last")
                                        .append(json[i].Title)
                                        .append("<br />");
            }

            $("#quickSearchResults").children(":last").css({ 'border-bottom': 'none' });

            if (json.length > 0) {
                $("#quickSearchResults").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#quickSearchResults").hide();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Basically this is my ajax function for a input hint system. On key up, it sends an ajax request to search and returns a small drop down of values.

What I'd like to do, is when a user clicks on one of the spans in the results, it copies that span to the textbox. So I tried this:

```
        $("#quickSearchResults").append($("<span class='quickSearchResult' />"))
                                .children(":last")
                                .append(json[i].Title)
                                .append("<br />")
                                .click(function(evt) {
                                    $("#searchBox").val(json[i].Title);    
                                });
```

But this does not work. I tried assigning a variable to json[i].Title and using that instead, but it seems to just always return the title of the last result. I'm thinking it's probably a binding issue, but don't know if there's a way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? Jquery **[Autocomplete](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm)** seems like it would fit your purpose

If not it will definitely give you insight as of how to do what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
    var title = json[i].Title;

    $("#quickSearchResults").append($("<span class='quickSearchResult' />"))
                            .children(":last")
                            .append(json[i].Title)
                            .append("<br />");
    })(i);
}
```

You would need to invoke a function so the `i` is stored and bound to a function instead of relying on the last value, I *think* something like this should work to create the closure. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a jQuery guru by any means, but would something like this work?

```
function setSearchBox()
{
    $("#searchBox").val($(this).data("title"))
}
```

and then in your AJAX response...

```
$("#quickSearchResults").append($("<span class='quickSearchResult' />"))
                        .children(":last")
                        .append(json[i].Title)
                        .append("<br />")
                        .data("title",json[i].Title)
                        .click(setSearchBox);
```